# Codenameone:How to get the mobile number of current sim card in real device?

Tags: codenameone

How to get the mobile number of current sim card in real device and how to read meassage from mobile .
 I just want to read sim card number and messages of mobile.
Can you please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: You may need to go deep into implementing native functionalities to read messages on a device. However, I'm not sure you can get sim card number on a device except if this is also possible with native development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile devices don't provide that information for security/privacy reasons. You can access it in some low level Android API's but since this isn't portable we don't expose that.

Notice that apps like whatsapp, uber, gettaxi etc. all ask you to type in your phone number then a verification code sent via an SMS. That's exactly what [JAT](https://www.codenameone.com/featured-jat.html) (which was built with Codename One) does.

Comment: We cannot intercept SMS messages since that isn't supported on iOS and was recently further restricted on Android

Comment: is there any another way to read message automatically and take OTP from message and validate it ?

Comment: No, you might be able to do something using native interfaces on Android but this isn't possible on iOS as far as I know and Apple is strictly against such things.