# Retrieve IMSI by using CodenameOne, Cordova and AngularJS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, codenameone

I use **Cordova Hybrid Apps in Codename One** and I would like retrieve the **IMSI** of the SIM card. Someone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't provide access to IMSI natively to protect users privacy. We provide `Display.getMsisdn()` but it won't work on most modern platforms.

I'm guessing what you are really asking is this [Codenameone:How to get the mobile number of current sim card in real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933059/codenameonehow-to-get-the-mobile-number-of-current-sim-card-in-real-device/38939095#38939095)

Comment: Thank you for your response Shai. Yes, with Android native was tried and it worked IMSI but we want to encode with a single code for all platforms. That's why we used Cordova Hybrid Apps in Codename One.

Comment: You can't do this natively on iOS so the functionality isn't feasible